# Combinations: A Generalization on a Classic Problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm asked the following question:

---

> How many integers from $1$ to $10,000$, inclusive, are multiples of $5$ or $7$ or both?

---

I've got the answer using this:

```
unsigned a_5 = 0;
unsigned a_7 = 0;
unsigned a_both = 0;
unsigned a_35 = 0;

for( unsigned i = 1 ; i <= 10000 ; ++i )
{
    if( i % 5 == 0 )
    {
        ++a_5;
    }
    if( i % 7 == 0 )
    {
        ++a_7;
    }
    if( ( i % 5 == 0 ) &&  (i % 7 == 0 ) )
    {
        ++a_both;
    }

    if( i % 35 == 0 )
    {
        ++a_35;
    }
}

cout << "a_5 = " << a_5 << endl << endl;
cout << "a_7 = " << a_7 << endl << endl;
cout << "a_both = " << a_both << endl << endl;
cout << "a_35 = " << a_35 << endl << endl;
```

---

What I'd like to know is in general

---

> How many integers from $a_m$ to $a_n$, inclusive, are multiples of $a_m\leq k\leq a_n$?

Comment: a_5 = 2000

a_7 = 1428

a_both = 285

a_35 = 285

Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Look for the number $u$ such that $(u-1)k < a_m \leq uk$, and the number $v$ such that $vk \leq a_n < (v+1)k$. These are the first and last multiples of k. The multiples of k will be $uk, (u+1)k, (u+2)k, \dots, vk$. (If you're a coder, you may recognise u as ceiling($a_m/k$), and v as floor($a_n/k$).) Then the question is: how many integers are there between u and v inclusive? The answer is $v - u + 1$.

Comment: The other thing to take into account is the "inclusion-exclusion" that goes on. When you count multiples of $5$ there are there some that are also multiples of $7$. When you count the multiples of $7$ there are some that are multiples of $5$. By adding these numbers you are counting twice those that are multiples of $5\times7$. In general, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: @RGB I don't think there's any inclusion-exclusion going on here!

Comment: I think that there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiples of $5$ in the given range are $1\cdot5,2\cdot5,\ldots,2000\cdot5$, so there are $2000$ of them. The multiples of $7$ are $1\cdot7,2\cdot7,\ldots,\left\lfloor\frac{10000}7\right\rfloor\cdot7=1428\cdot7$, so there are $1428$ of them. However, every multiple of $35$ is in both lists, so the sum $2000+1428$ counts those multiples of $35$ twice. These multiples are $1\cdot35,2\cdot35,\ldots,\left\lfloor\frac{10000}{35}\right\rfloor\cdot35=285\cdot35$, so there are $285$ of them. Thus, the number of integers from $1$ through $10,000$ that are multiples of $5$, of $7$, or of both is

$$2000+1428-285=3143\;.$$

The same ideas work in general: the number of multiples of $d$ between $1$ and $n$, inclusive, is $\left\lfloor\frac{n}d\right\rfloor$. For multiples of more than two numbers, however, you’ll need to use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) in greater generality to deal properly with the integers that are multiples of more than one of the numbers.